# Duplicating courses in Moodle by using REST webservice with Python

Tags: python, rest, web-services, moodle-api

I'm really struggling to get my code for duplicating moodle courses via REST to work, just couldn't figure out the reason:

```
import requests
import json

token = 'mytoken123'
domainname = 'https://example.com'

functionname = 'core_course_duplicate_course'

# Course ID of the course to be duplicated
courseid = 61  # Replace with your course ID

# New course details
newcoursedata = {
    'fullname': 'New Course Full Name',
    'shortname': 'NewCourseShortName',
    'categoryid': 10,
    'visible': 1,
}

restformat = 'json'  # Also possible to use 'xml'

data = {
    'courseid': courseid,
    'options': newcoursedata,
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# REST CALL
serverurl = f'{domainname}/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken={token}&wsfunction={functionname}&moodlewsrestformat={restformat}'
response = requests.post(serverurl, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

# Print response
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
```

The error message is:

```
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "invalid parameter value (Missing required key in single structure: courseid)",
    "debuginfo": "Missing required key in single structure: courseid"
}
```

What I'm missing here?
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the format of the options data array. This code works:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

api = 'https://example.com/webservice/rest/server.php'
courseid = 61
categoryid = 10
token = '1234567890'

fullname = 'New Course Full Name'
shortname = 'NewCourseShortName'

params = {
    'wstoken': token,
    'wsfunction': 'core_course_duplicate_course',
    'courseid': courseid,
    'fullname': fullname,
    'shortname': shortname,
    'categoryid': categoryid,
    'options[0][name]': 'users',
    'options[0][value]': '0',
    'moodlewsrestformat': 'json'
}

# Encode the parameters
encoded_params = urlencode(params)

# Construct the URL
url = f"{api}?{encoded_params}"

# REST CALL
response = requests.post(url)

# Print response
print(response.json())
```